# Find specific option with apex?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a select which contains the following option:

```
<select class="selectpicker" id="uploaded-files">
   <option value="hello' world.pdf">hello' world.pdf</option>
</select>
```

I'm trying to select the option with the value `hello' world.pdf` but I got the following error:

> Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #uploaded-files option[value='"hello' world.pdf"']

this is my code:

```
let fileName = "hello' world.pdf";
$("#uploaded-files option[value='" + fileName + "']").remove();
```

Comment: What would happen if you put the filename in manually (ie built the string yourself), you'd get `"#uploaded-files option[value='hello' world.pdf']"` - can you see the problem there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue here of course is that by time `fileName` is evaluated, it can contain characters that render your jQuery selector syntax invalid.

You *could* come up with a way of escaping the `fileName` string.

Or, you could take the easier route of avoiding jQuery selectors for this altogether, and use [`.filter()`](https://api.jquery.com/filter/) instead:

```
$("#uploaded-files option").filter(function(){
    return $(this).prop('value') === fileName;
}).remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

Please refer below code.

```js
let fileName = "hello' world.pdf";
$('#uploaded-files').children('option[value="' + fileName + '"]').remove()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="selectpicker" id="uploaded-files">
  <option value="hello' world.pdf">hello' world.pdf</option>
</select>
```

Comment: This works well until we come across a `fileName` that contains a `"` (or any other syntax-breaking character) instead of `'`.

Comment: @George can you provide such filename, I would like to check it.

Comment: Well.. `hello" world.pdf`?